# How to change "container" class to "container-fluid" class in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have installed a template in wordpress and now I am editing some parts of it using elementor. But a part of it has a class of "container" but I will like to change it to "container-fluid". Please How can I achieve that.

I know how to change some css styles using the "additional css" in wordpress customizer but I don't know how to achieve that with this. I have also tried editing using the "edit theme" but I don't know the exact file to change the class.

[image: Present situation using the conatiner class]

[image: Result Expected which should be using the container-fluid class]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to the issue just now.

On the list of all pages, I clicked on the quick edit where I then set the template to elementor full width which did the magic.

Thanks